# Django: overlapping label and radio button options

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, radio-button, label

I am using django crispy_forms.helper and crispy_forms.layout to create radio button with options. The label and radio button options are overlapping.

The code which i am using is :

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, HTML, Layout, Row, Div, Fieldset,ButtonHolder,Column
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import InlineRadios, PrependedAppendedText, Div

ROUTER_OPTIONS = (
('', 'Choose router...'),
('FIP', 'First IP in range'),
('AM', 'Add Manually')
 )
class DhcpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    router = forms.ChoiceField(label='Router',
                           choices=ROUTER_OPTIONS,
                           initial='', widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(DhcpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.helper = FormHelper()
            self.helper.form_method = 'post'
            self.helper.layout = Layout(
                                    Row(
            Column('dhcp_member', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
            Column('router', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
            css_class='form-row'
        )
```

*html*

```
{% block content %}
{% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}
```

The view which i am getting:

[overlapped view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EMov.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Choice field Add the style function and set the display as flex given below.

```
Column('router', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0', style='display: flex')
```